# Prevent scroll reset in AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dom, web

I have a div container that gets its content modified every 3 seconds by a javascript function. The function is initially called by the onload event of the body tag.

```
function showNow(){

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
       xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
   };

   xmlhttp.open("GET", "tab.php", true);
   xmlhttp.send();

   setTimeout(showNow, 3000);
}
```

The content is being refreshed every 3 seconds. The only problem is that the scroll position is being reset and hence my page jumps back to beginning. This is affecting the usability highly.

Can anyone please suggest a solution?

Comment: I am not quite sure when the scroll is being reset. Is there anyway in which I can check this?

Comment: I found the culprit. The problem was that when the code is being swapped, there is no content in the div tag. So, the scroll moves back. Setting the height property of the div tag is a quick fix for this. @Jeffrey 's solution "should" technically work. But its not. Maybe someone can throw more light on this! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before the innerHTML is set, you could get the `txtHint` element's `scrollTop` property. Then, after the text is added, set that variable to `scrollTop` again.

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
    var scroll = document.body.scrollTop;
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    document.body.scrollTop = scroll;
 }
```

Comment: The entire page goes back to the top. There is no scrollable element within the page.

Comment: Nope, still no joy. Incidentally, the way you suggested just now is very similar to what felipeoriani has suggested below.

Comment: @Gowtham yeah. I just assumed that you wanted a scroll effect on an inner popup element or something. Anyway, that code works for me. You are replacing the old `if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){}` block right? Also, what browser are you using?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8720/discussion-between-gowtham-and-jeffrey-sweeney)

Comment: I am replacing the block. I tried the code on IE 9, opera and chrome.

Comment: Well, that code "should" work. Make sure there are no errors in the error console, and also ensure that the scroll isn't being set by anything else (like a library).

Comment: This is the only code I am using on the page at the moment. Even then its not working. Any more ides?

Comment: Just check the error console. Also, try outputting the `scrollTop` property to the console to ensure it is correct. Here's the MDN page on the `scrollTop` property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollTop

Comment: Ill keep trying. Thanks for all the help! I marked your reply as the answer. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `window.scrollTo(x, y)` to set the position of scroll, for sample:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
   document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
   window.scrollTo(0, 0); //stay on the top
}
```

Comment: +1 I forgot about the `scrollTo` function. Except, that may only apply to the `window` object.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I already tried this, but it was not working! :(

Comment: Sorry, the code was wrong, you should set window.scrollTo(0, 0); but if you solve the problem, great! :)

Answer (score 4):

I'm french so forgive me for my bad English

I had the same thing on my page : when I clicked on the link, the XHR request reseted my scroll on full top. I've found my mistake...a very stupid one... 
Check your HTML, if your "onClick" is in a `<a>` tag, check you've not written `<a href="#" onClick="myFunction()">`...
That was my mistake, and just `<a onClick="myFunction()">` don't reset the scroll x)

Hope I've helped you

Comment: It is generally recommended to have the onclick event handler as "myfunction(); return false;". The href link can still be "#"

Answer (score 1):

try adding

`return false;`

at end of the ajax request

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this was answered completely.

I had the same problem, trying all solutions above did not solve it. What i found was that refreshing the innerHTML actually made the Scrollbar disappear for a very short period of time (because the entire page becomes a lot smaller in height as the content gets refreshed), subsequently when content reappears (and the Scrollbar) the browser has no way of knowing where he was before the call and hence scrolls all the way up.

My own solution was very simple and does not involve catching events etc..., I added a column which I filled with a spacer.gif the height of the div I intend to refresh. That way the entire page layout itself never actually gets distorted, the Scrollbar never disappear even a short period of time.

```
<table width="30%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
    <img src="/images/spacer.gif" width="0" height="170"/>   <-- adding the extra column to keep the height always the same.
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="content">
        <script>loadnewusermenu()</script> <-- content getting refreshed
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope it makes sense.
DjYoy